# What is this warning about cheating?

Tags: pokemon-go

In a PoGO chat group somebody shared this screenshot. He told us that he just wanted to show us that the PoGO application had a new security protocol for 3rd party applications. Is this true?

Is this warning a standard warning for all players?

If yes, why did the application just warn him? Is he cheating?

[image]

Comment: Looks fake to me

Comment: Maybe he can be a cheater but I think it isn't fake.

Comment: i agree with Иво in that it looks fake, niantic does not give warnings for cheating, they just ban. Not to mention the fact that if they were using a third party application you wouldn't even see the normal UI.

Comment: Why do you think it's legit?  It doesn't match the UI of other pop ups the game provides, and isn't even filled in.  I think someone's trolling you.

Comment: Why you think that I am trolled by someone? Is it because just you think this pop up isn't like other pop ups? Anyway, I searched before and found nothing. But just now I found some pictures on Google Search like this pop up. If you want to check it here is the link. goo.gl/0bSBMk

Comment: It's been [reported over on reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/TheSilphRoad/comments/562k85/cheating_banner/) that some players are seeing a similar message, however, the reported messages actually have descriptive text in them.  The text in this image appears to be object names, not actual message text. Is your "friend" using the official download, or sideloading an APK?

Comment: It's pretty silly that people think this looks fake when it would only look like this if it wasn't fake.

Comment: @Tester101 what is it mean "friend"? Are you trying to bringing me under suspicion? Next time, can you please make a comment just about the question, not about me? Thank you. This [image](http://imgur.com/V8M19IV) is for your "friend" suspicion.

And yes, in my county every player is sidedownloading the application as APK because it doesn't officialy released yet. Obviously, this warning shouldn't be about official download.

Comment: @Attalos Sorry, the "friend" comment was meant as a joke.  The reason I ask about sideloading, is because it seems like the code to pop the message was in place, but the message text was not yet in the APK.  That's why you're seeing the message in that form, instead of the actual message text.

Comment: We only support the official PoGo app.  Since you and your friend are sideloading it, it stands to reason that others may be injecting malicious or broken code into it.  Once the official app does this, then we can support it.

Comment: @ИвоНедев http://media02.hongkiat.com/pokemongo-security-updates/pokemongo-warning-captcha.jpg

Answer (score -3):

I'm not sure if that screenshot is right, but you *can* get banned for cheating (using a 3rd party app). I have heard people just get banned without a warning and only get an email saying they got banned.

Niantic released an [official statement](http://pokemongolive.com/en/post/cheating-bans/) saying they are taking action against cheaters

Comment: This looks like an attempt to respond to the comment thread on the question.